# subprocess.run(["huggingface-cli", "login", "--token", TOKEN]) works on mac but not on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, subprocess

I am tring to run `subprocess.run(["huggingface-cli", "login", "--token", TOKEN])` in a Jupyter notebook, which works on Mac but gets the following error on Ubuntu. I checked that `pip install huggingface_hub` has been executed.

`subprocess.run(["git", "lfs", "install"])` works.

`!huggingface-cli login` in the jupyter cell gets the error `/bin/bash: huggingface-cli: command not found`

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `huggingface_hub` is not in your path env variable for your `Ubuntu` system, it is not the same between your `jupyter` and your `terminal` session

here what you can do, get the `path` of the executable `pip show huggingface_hub | grep Location` then update the path in your jupyter notebook, like for example:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

huggingface_bin_path = "/home/user/.local/bin"
os.environ["PATH"] = f"{huggingface_bin_path}:{os.environ['PATH']}"

subprocess.run(["huggingface-cli", "login", "--token", TOKEN])
```

replace `/home/user/.local/bin` and `TOKEN` with the correct one, then it should work

Comment: Thanks, this works. I also used `which huggingface_hub` to find the path.

Answer (score 1):

jupyter or colab

!huggingface-cli login --token hf_KjwGsxQLURmKdftszadObzCcRXaeTC